# Set section and subsection header to ttf font in KOMA-script

Tags: fonts, fontspec, koma-script

I'd like to set a custom font I acquired for all section and subsection headers in a `scratcl` paper I'm writing. It's a `ttf` and installed correctly on my Mac.

I know about `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont`, and I also have found the `fontspec` package, but all that seems to do is set the font for the entire document via `\setmainfont`, or for a section via `\fontspec` if I understand correctly.

I just can't seem to add one and one here, so to recap: how do I set (sub)section headers to a font installed on my Mac?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use the system fonts you need to use `xe(la)tex` or `lualatex` instead of `(pdf)latex`. And with `fontspec` you can define a new family with `\newfontfamily`.

```
% I'm a UNICODE/UTF-8 encoded file!
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\atfamily{American Typewriter}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\atfamily}

% for testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Save this file as UTF-8 file and compile it with `xelatex` then you’ll get this.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Also thanks for using `\addtokomafont`, I hate having to figure out sizes and stuff :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use pdf(la)tex you will have to generate the various support files needed: metrics `.tfm`, encoding files, font definition files, map files, perhaps virtual font files.

With xelatex/lualatex you can use the font directly:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec,color}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\color{red}\fontspec{Times New Roman}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}
\section{text}
\subsection{text}
\end{document}
```